# Javascript ES2015: работа import и export

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, импорт, export

Приветствую

Проконсультируйте пожалуйста по вопросу использования import и export в javascript (es2015)

Прочитав про import/export в ES2015 не понял - можно ли использовать их сами по себе, т.е.

**index.html:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type = 'text/javascript' src = 'main.js'></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <script type = 'text/javascript'>

            console.log(getData());

        </script>
    </body>  
</html>
```

**main.js**

```
import {getValue} from "./module"

function getData()
{
    return getValue(3);
}
```

**module.js**

```
export function getValue(value)
{
    return value * 5;
}
```

В итоге выдаются ошибки:

```
main.js:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
index.html:11 Uncaught ReferenceError: getData is not defined
    at index.html:11
```

В чем ошибка? Или я вообще неправильно понимаю, как эти модули должны использоваться? Просто думал, что в ES2015 теперь из JS с помощью модулей можно подгружать начинку других JS

Comment: @Air это совершенно неправильно

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/company/tuturu/blog/326716/ есть хорошая статья на эту тему:)

Comment: а так вообще надо использовать дополнительные инструменты (на ваш выбор) для работы с модулями.

Comment: @ИльяПаймушкин, Хорошая статья)))  Благодарю...